# php socket server Local VS. online vps

Tags: php, sockets, vps

im trying to create a simple socket server.
When im running it on localhost everything works just fine.

But when im uploading the socket server to my vps and runs it,
it starts the server but nothing happens when it try to write to it. **(The client.php runs on localhost, dont know if thats even posible to do).**

Client PHP:

```
<?php

$host = "93.191.155.164";
//localhost: $host = "127.0.0.1";

$port = 4643;

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Client</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="input" />
        <input type="submit" name="btn" />
    </form>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
            if($_POST['input'] != ''){
                $message = $_POST['input'];

                $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
                socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");
                socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");

                if (false == (@$result = socket_read($socket, 1024))) {
                    echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
                }else{
                    echo "Svar fra Server  :".$result . "\n";
                }
                socket_close($socket);
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Server PHP:

```
<?php

$host    = "0.0.0.0";
$port    = 4643;

set_time_limit(0);

if (($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}else{
    echo "Master socket er oprettet OK\n";
}

if (socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
}else{
    echo "Binding af port og adresse er OK\n";
}

if (socket_listen($socket, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
}else{
    echo "Lytter for inkommende data OK\n";
}

while(true){
// lav en ny socket til at håntere komunikation.
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Kan ikke acceptere indkommende data\n");


//inputtet fra clienten.
//input indeholder dataen der er sendt fra clienten.
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Kan ikke lease dataen\n");
$output = "Denne besked kommer fra serveren.";

echo $input . " MSG er modtaget.";


socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen($output)) or die("Kunne ikke skrive tilbage\n");

socket_close($spawn);

}

socket_close($socket);
?>
```

I will be greatefull for any help i can get, and thx for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you have firewall in place. Try to run the client on server. And then study iptables.